# Modify overlapping geom_boxplot width to span entire x range used for calculations

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to create a ggplot graph, where boxplots are on the same graph as the points used for their calculation.

The points are count data, and the goal of the boxplot is to show how the distribution of those points change when different timeframes from present are used for their calculation.  I would like to get it so all boxplots have their right side edge aligned with the last date, and have a width that extends the left hand side of boxplot to the first year considered.

I have included the data to plot below.  I have attempted to include `varwidth=T`, but specifying width in aesthetics is not recognized as either a variable or static number, and has no effect outside the aesthetics.

Any advice on if this is possible and how to achieve would be appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

CUTS <- structure(list(`Years to Consider` = c(3, 5, 9, 18, 27), 
    Year = c(2014,2012, 2008, 1999, 1990)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")  

data <- structure(list(
  Year = c(1978, 1979, 1980, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985,1986, 1987, 1988, 
           1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997,1998, 1999, 
           2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2009, 2010, 2012, 2014,2017),
  Total = c(110, 262, 240, 711, 710, 775, 985, 929, 933,670, 1162, 
            1215, 1408, 1194, 1136, 1321, 1327, 1689, 2121, 1754, 
            2167, 2051, 2862, 2861, 1784, 2093, 1367, 1003, 685, 451), 
  Lambda = c(NA, 2.38181818181818, 0.916030534351145, 1.72119144780585, 
             0.9985935302391, 1.09154929577465, 1.27096774193548, 
             0.943147208121827, 1.0043057050592, 0.718113612004287, 
             1.73432835820896, 1.04561101549053, 1.15884773662551,
             0.848011363636364, 0.975409547623274, 1.16285211267606, 
             1.00454201362604,1.27279577995479, 1.25577264653641, 
             0.826968411126827, 1.23546180159635,0.946469773880941, 
             1.3954168698196, 0.999650593990217, 0.888626474900967,
             1.08314647117872, 0.653129479216436, 0.856576606076504, 
             0.826408583305086,0.869952065260471)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-30L))

####data for entire period
BOX_DATA <-data %>%  mutate(LAMB_YEARS=last(Year)-first(Year), FIRST_YEAR=first(Year))

###select all data with year greater than cutoffs in CUTS data frame up to last year, 
###assign variable for number of years conisdered, bind to enitre period
for(i in CUTS$Year){
  temp_box <- data %>% filter(Year>=i) %>% select(Year, Total,Lambda) %>% 
    mutate(LAMB_YEARS=2017-i, FIRST_YEAR=i)
  BOX_DATA <- rbind(BOX_DATA, temp_box)      
}
####make lamb years factor for boxplot grouping define order so largest draw on bottom
BOX_DATA$LAMB_YEARS <- factor(BOX_DATA$LAMB_YEARS, levels=c(39,27,18,9,5,3))

####make graph
ggplot(data, aes(Year, Lambda)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   geom_boxplot(data=BOX_DATA, aes(fill=LAMB_YEARS), alpha=.3)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your expected output; can you provide a mock-up plot?

Comment: @MauritsEvers  It would be similar to the graph created at end of example, except the width of the box for lamb years:39 would extend from 2017 to 1978, box for lamb years: 27 would extend from 2017 to 1990, etc...

Comment: I edited your post to include the original figure. I still don't understand what you're after. I think a mock-up figure would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image: plot]

Code below, produced by calculating the boxplot values manually & plotting them using `geom_rect()` & `geom_segment()`, because `geom_boxplot()`'s width parameter really isn't meant for this.

I'm not sure if this is an effective way to visualize the data, though. If you use this to convey a point to your audience, you probably want to spend some time explaining how it should be interpreted.

```
BOX_DATA2 <- BOX_DATA %>%
  filter(!is.na(Lambda)) %>%
  group_by(LAMB_YEARS) %>%
  summarise(xmin = min(Year),
            xmax = max(Year),

            y.q25 = quantile(Lambda, 0.25),
            y.q50 = quantile(Lambda, 0.5),
            y.q75 = quantile(Lambda, 0.75),

            ymin = min(Lambda[Lambda >= y.q25 - 1.5 * IQR(Lambda)]), 
            ymax = max(Lambda[Lambda <= y.q75 + 1.5 * IQR(Lambda)])) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = data, aes(Year, Lambda)) +
  geom_rect(data = BOX_DATA2,                # create box for box plot
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,
                ymin = y.q25, ymax = y.q75,
                fill = LAMB_YEARS), 
            alpha = 0.3, color = "black") +
  geom_segment(data = BOX_DATA2,             # add median line
               aes(x = xmin, xend = xmax,
                   y = y.q50, yend = y.q50)) +
  geom_segment(data = BOX_DATA2,             # add whiskers
               aes(x = (xmin + xmax) / 2, xend = (xmin + xmax) / 2,
                   y = ymin, yend = ymax))
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to achieve.  I agree might not be the best way to represent it, sort of became an issue of why can't I figure out how to do this.  Thank you for your time and response.